# How to upgrade ubuntu step by step

Tags: upgrade, troubleshooting

I try to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04 (or upper why not).
I read in release notes that I should first upgrade to 12.10 before 13.04.

But when I use the *update-manager -d* command, the program purposes to install only the release 14.04.
How can I chose the target version ?

(I tried to upgrade to 14.04 but I had an error message:

```
W:Impossible de récupérer http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Impossible de récupérer http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.)
```

Comment: 14.04 is in development and thus not supported here. If you wish to test 14.04 I suggest you do a fresh install on a test box/partition/virtualbox or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This method allows a step by step upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1327424&p=8322347#post8322347) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/34457/208026).